# How to integrate $\int \frac 1 {\begin{pmatrix}\frac1 3 t - 8\end{pmatrix}^5} \,dt$ by substitution?

Tags: calculus, integration

I am required to solve this question via integration by an appropriate substitution. This is the first time I am doing it with no help on the substitution part. Hence, could somebody help me check this working?

$$
\begin{align*}
\int \frac 1 {\begin{pmatrix}\frac1 3 t - 8\end{pmatrix}^5} \,dt
= 3\int \frac 1 {\begin{pmatrix}\frac1 3 t - 8\end{pmatrix}^5} \,\frac 1 3dt
\end{align*}
$$

Consider the substitution $u = \begin{pmatrix}\frac 1 3 t -8\end{pmatrix}$ and so $du = \frac 1 3 dt$ and perform the substitution

$$
\begin{align*}
3\int \frac 1 {\begin{pmatrix}\frac1 3 t - 8\end{pmatrix}^5} \,\frac 1 3dt
&= 3\int\frac 1 {u^5} \, du
\\&= -\frac 3 4 u^{-4} + C
\\&= -\frac 3 4 \begin{pmatrix}\frac 1 3 t -8\end{pmatrix}^{-4} +C
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: It's alright except In final answer, you have written $x$ in place of $t$

Comment: @Avatar Thanks, I realized and deleted my comment.

Comment: Okay, made the appropriate changes!

Comment: Comments like "Resolved" in the title tend to just cause clutter.  It's clear on the front page whether there are answers or not, and if one has been accepted.  I've reverted the title.

Comment: +1 Excellent question and very well-asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you to all who have helped, my proposed solution has been verified and is correct.

Comment: +1, You could have computed faster if you had omitted the first algebraic transformation
$$
\int \frac{1}{(\frac{1}{3}t-8)^{5}}dt=\int \frac{1}{u^{5}}3du,\qquad u=\frac{1}{3}t-8,du=\frac{1}{3}dt,dt=3du.
$$